# Differentiating between different Colliders in OnParticleCollision

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I currently have a mechanic where a constant jet of water is spraying.
If the water hits the player, they take damage. If the water hits an umbrella, He doesn't.

I am having trouble integrating this mechanic due to not knowing how to differentiate between different parent/child colliders using OnParticleCollision

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine;

public class Health : MonoBehaviour {

public float startingHealth = 100f;
public float health;



public Slider healthSlider;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    health = startingHealth;
}

void OnParticleCollision(GameObject offender)
{
    if (offender.gameObject.name == "hoseSystem") //collided with BoxCollider. 
    {
        health -= 0.5f;
        healthSlider.value = health;
    }
}
// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
}
}
```

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding what you need. Why is the `OnParticleCollision` inside the health class? And what do you mean by differentiating different colliders? Do you mean different players, or different particle types?

Please elaborate a bit on that so I can help further.

Comment: I want it so that if he particles from the particle system hit the boxcollider, I take damage. If it hits the spherecollider. I don’t take damage. How would I perform this? This is why it is in the health script.

Comment: So you have two colliders on the same GameObject, or is it a different GameObject for the player & another for the Umbrella?

Comment: Boxclolider on main object, umbrella collided on empty child

Comment: could you provide your Particle System -> Collision setup in the question? A picture would be very convenient.

Comment: https://ufile.io/jvifu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, let's clarify a few things to get our heads around the way collision in general works in Unity.

#### Collision

- An entity requires a rigidbody for collision to work.
- Collision events fire when a parent object *or any of it's children* are hit by an object. In this case, they are treated as a single entity.
- Collision events fire on *both sides*. i.e. Water hose particles will also receive the collision event.

#### Particle systems

- Particle systems are mainly meant to be used for visuals, as they are very performance intensive.
- Particle systems' `OnParticleCollision` does not provide nearly the same level of functionality as `RigidBody.OnCollisionEnter`. This is by design in Unity.
- It is generally advised against using particles for interactions like the one you're trying to achieve.

Now to answer your question, although this is really sub-optimal, one way to do it would be to check the collision from the particle system, and have it decrease the health of the object by abusing the fact that `GetComponent` does not look through children and/or parents of the object that got hit.

The logic would be as follow:

1. Particle collides with object.
2. Particle fetches the "Health" component of the object.
3. Particle calls "Damage" on the aforementioned component.

In practice this would translate to:

```
public class WaterHose : MonoBehaviour {

private void OnParticleCollision(GameObject other)
{
    //Get the component specifically in the gameobject we hit
    //This by default ignores parents/children.
    Health health = other.GetComponent<Health>();
    if (health != null)
        health.Damage(5);
}
}
```

and

```
public class Health : MonoBehaviour {

public float health;

void Start () {
    health = 150f;
}

public void Damage(float amount)
{
    health -= amount;
}
}
```

`Health` goes on the player, `WaterHose` goes on the water gun.

Keep in mind that this is still *very* bad design.

I would recommend to instead use `RayCasts` on set intervals, the same way you would fire a projectile-less gun in Unity, and use the particles only for the effects.

Update:
As per OP's request, you could add a `RigidBody` to your umbrella, make sure you set `isKinematic` field to `true`.
This, by default will enable different collision detection from `Player`, `Umbrella` and `WaterHose` to know which body it hit.

The following code snippet demonstrates this:

```
public class WaterHose : MonoBehaviour {

private void OnParticleCollision(GameObject other)
{
    Collider col = other.GetComponent<Collider>();

    if (col is CapsuleCollider)
        Debug.Log("We hit the player!");
    else if (col is BoxCollider)
        Debug.Log("We hit the umbrella!");
}
}
```

It's worth noting that this is still very bad design and I strongly recommend using `RayCasts` instead.

Comment: Thank you for the information, I totally understand that this is suboptimal and now understand that ray casts are the way to go. However this still does not answer my original post. I would like to know how I can detect which collider , not just any collision, has happened between my particle system and then carry out a different task for each given input. This is why I wanted to take damage if The particle system collided with my player collided, a box collided, and for nothing to happen when it hits my sphere collided. It doesn’t matter where they are they are referenced as public objects

Comment: @MikeyLee Well, there is a very hacky approach that you could use, it didn't feel right to include it in the answer. Let me test it on my side then I'll update the answer.

Comment: Thank you, I will have training so I won’t be able to get back to you till later

Comment: @MikeyLee I've added more details, let me know if you still need anything else.